# How to update database courses in openedx

Tags: sql, django, openedx

I am trying to update my database entries.
after restoring sql file, it is showing in database.
but not updated in openedx site (lms /cms).

also in home page it shows old entries.
How can i update gui entries??

Answer (score 1):

It seems that courses are not being re-indexed. You need to re-index all your courses.

```
./manage.py cms reindex_course --all --settings aws (or) devstack
```

It may take long if you have a large database of courses.

For removing old entries:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/courseware_index/course_info/_query' -d '{"term" : { "course" : "old_course_id" }}'

curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/courseware_index/courseware_content/_query' -d '{"term" : { "course" : "old_course_id" }}'
```